# How to use regex in this scenario?

Tags: regex

This is the raw text:

> 1. Choose the concept you want to understand  2. Take a blank piece of paper, write the name of that concept at the top of the page  3.
>      Explain the idea to yourself as if you were teaching it to someone who
>      does not understand it at all  4. Whenever you get stuck, go back to
>      the reference material, lectures or a teacher assistant and re-read or
>      re-learn the material until you get it enough that you can explain it
>      on the paper  5. Whenever you write down a wordy or a confusing
>      explanation for something, try either to simplify the language, or
>      create an analogy to understand it better  6. If you want to
>      understand something even better or remember it even better, further
>      try to develop, simplify and improve the explanation  7. A good
>      self-test of what you've learned is to go through your technique
>      without looking at any reference material at any point and see if you
>      can explain it deeply

This is the desired formatted text:

Choose the concept you want to understand
Take a blank piece of paper, write the name of that concept at the top of the page
Explain the idea to yourself as if you were teaching it to someone who does not understand it at all
Whenever you get stuck, go back to the reference material, lectures or a teacher assistant and re-read or re-learn the material until you get it enough that you can explain it on the paper
Whenever you write down a wordy or a confusing explanation for something, try either to simplify the language, or create an analogy to understand it better

So I need to perform the following operations in order:

1. Newline before each number
2. Remove the number and the succeeding (.) character

How might I accomplish this using http://www.regexr.com/ + the correct regex command?  Or is regex the right tool for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple replace:

```
s/\d+\./\n/g
```

which means

```
\d+  -->any sequence of digits
\.      -->a dot

\n      -->a newline
```

Comment: I tried pasting your solution into www.regexr.com , but it came up with no match.  Is this the limitation of regexr itself?